# Assign function, ignore first value

Tags: python, python-2.7

First let me say I don't think it is a duplicate. I checked [Ignore python multiple return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431866/ignore-python-multiple-return-value) already. This isn't quite what I need.

So, I have a function f:

```
def f(parameters):
    return a,b # returns two values
```

defined in `module1.py`. Now, I want another class to be aware of this function, so I do:

```
import module1

Class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.function = module1.f
```

This, of course, happens in `module2.py`. I need to call it in yet another module,
`module3.py` like so:

```
import module2

instance = module2.MyClass()

otherFunction(args, instance.function  )
```

Here's the catch: the second argument of `otherFunction` has to be a function that returns a single value (currently, it returns two). I tried

```
import module1

Class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.function = module1.f[0]
```

But this does not work. Any ideas? I cannot change `module3.py`. I can change the others but then I would have to do a bunch of changes to my project and this seems to be very painful.
I use python 2.6. I would be happy if whatever solution you find would also work for python3, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to accept an arbitrary function then you could use lambdas or a wrapper function:

```
self.function = lambda *args: module1.f(*args)[0]
```

Otherwise, check out @Christian's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a decorator:

```
def mydecorator(f):
    def w(*args, **kwargs):
        r = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return r[0]
    return w

@mydecorator
def f(a, b):
    return a + 2, b + 3 # returns two values

print f(1, 2) # 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a lambda that wraps around `f`:

```
Class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.function = lambda parameters: module1.f(parameters)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

OK this might have been a dumb question:

In `module1.py` I do:

```
def f(parameters):
    retrun a,b # returns two values

def ff(parameters):
    a, b = f(parameters)
    return a
```

and use `ff` instead of `f`.