# php (or python) listen to unix domain stream socket

Tags: php, python, sockets, unix-socket

I need to create a script that listens to a unix socket and forward the incoming stream to a bot. The scripts are unable to connect. The issues seems to be related to the order of things.

**Proof of case**

I have created a socket and I am able to write to it.
In session 1, I create a listener connection

```
nc -lU /tmp/tg.sck
```

In session 2, I write to the socket.

```
 while true; do echo "hello"; sleep 2; done | nc -U /tmp/tg.sck
```

The above only works if I do it in that order. 
==> Writing before you have a listener results in an error.

**Using scripts (does not work)**

When I replace the listing process with a PHP (or Python) script, the connection is refused because the socket is not opened.

```
$ python test.py 
Connecting...
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

or

```
$ php test.php 
Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to unix:///tmp/tg.sck:-1 (Connection refused)
```

**Changing the order of things**

If I start a working listener using the command `nc -lU /tmp/tg.sck` then the script does not die, but the writer process does.

**Listener scripts**

```
import socket
import sys

server_address = '/tmp/tg.sck'  # Analogous to TCP (address, port) pair
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(server_address)
sock.recv(512)
```

and the php script

```
$fp = fsockopen('unix:///tmp/tg.sck', -1, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
  echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
  while (!feof($fp)) {
    echo fgets($fp, 4096);
  }
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I replace the listing process
>   ...
>
> ```
> sock.connect(server_address)
> ```

This does not listen but it connects.
To listen use `bind`,`listen` and `accept` the same way as you would do with other listing sockets (TCP, UDP):

```
server_address = '/tmp/tg.sck'  # Analogous to TCP (address, port) pair
os.unlink(server_address)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(2)
c,_ = sock.accept()
print c.recv(512)
```

Comment: Great solution @steffen. Can you explain the line c,_ =  ....  (I am a python newbie, and not seen this before).

Comment: @crafter: `c,_ = ...` just means to get the two arguments returned by `accept` but ignore the second one since it is not needed in the code.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251861/how-to-elegantly-ignore-some-return-values-of-a-python-function