# Getting Msg Ids from Telegram CLI running as daemon

Tags: python, bash, lua, telegram

I am running Telegram-CLI as a daemon .

I can successfully connect to my daemon using netcat on localhost host and send commands to it in the form of:

```
echo -e 'msg user whatever' | nc.traditional -w 1 127.0.0.1 1234
```

However, when I connect nc to my telegram daemon I don't see any output from all the telegram events such as when I run telegram-cli in independent mode .

How can I access all telegram events from my telegram-cli daemon and get the msg_id for each of them ?

Comment: I had a similar issue (not too similar to be a duplicate). Have a look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598089/php-or-python-listen-to-unix-domain-stream-socket

Comment: Try using the -lU option with nc