# Can a Python function return only the second of two values?

Tags: python, matlab, function, return

I have a Python function that returns multiple values. As an example for this question, consider the function below, which returns two values.

```
def function():
    ...
    return x, y
```

I know this function can return both values `x, y = function()`. But is it possible for this function to only return the second value?

In MATLAB, for example, it would be possible to do something like this: `~, y = function()`. I have not found an equivalent approach in Python.

Comment: `x = function()` also gets both values. If you try that, you'll see that x will be a tuple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore python multiple return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431866/ignore-python-multiple-return-value)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The pythonic idiom is just to ignore the first return value by assigning it to `_`:

```
_, y = function()
```

Answer (score 10):

The closest syntax you are looking is:

```
function()[1]
```

which will return the second element, since function's result can be considered a tuple of size 2.