# Return values automatically in python class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a new python user. Thus it might be very silly. But what is the best way to run a class automatically (which has several functions inside) and return the result for a given value. for example:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
    def funct1(self):
       return (self.x)**2
       ##or any other function
    def funct2(self,y):
       return y/100.0
       ##or any other function
    def wrapper(self):
        y=self.funct1()
        z=self.funct2(y)
        ##or other combination of functions
        return z
```

Right now to run this, I am using:

```
run=MyClass(5)
run.wrapper()
```

But I want to run like this:

```
MyClass(5)
```

Which will return a value and can be saved inside a variable with out needing to use the wrapper function.

Comment: Do not use a class if you do not want to keep its instance, it seems like it's a function you want

Comment: 1. You could call `wrapper` inside `__init__` (but keep in mind that `__init__` can not return a value, so you'd still need to use an attribute to store the result). 2. I'm not sure `MyClass` even deserves to be  / should be a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a functor as below:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
    def funct1(self):
       return (self.x)**2
       ##or any other function
    def funct2(self,y):
       return y/100.0
       ##or any other function
    def __call__(self):
        y=self.funct1()
        z=self.funct2(y)
        ##or other combination of functions
        return z
```

The call to this functor will be like as follow:

```
MyClass(5)()   # Second () will call the method __call__. and first one will call constructor
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

So when you write `MyClass(5)`, you're instatiating a new instance of *that* class: `MyClass` and so the short answer is **no**, you do need the wrapper because when you instantiate the class it will necessarily return the object and not a certain value.

If you want to just return a value based on the input (say `5`) consider using a `function` instead.

The function would be like:

```
   def my_func(x):
        y = x**2
        z = y/100.0
        return z
```

There a lots of reasons to use classes, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33072722/4443226 -- but if you're just concerned with the output of an operation/equation/function then I'd stick with functions.

Answer (score -1):

`__init__` method should return `None`.
[documentation link](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__init__#object.__init__)

> no non-None value may be returned by **init**()