# How can a function optionally return one or more values

Tags: python, return

What is the preferred way to ignore an optional return values of function f()?

a)

```
foo, _ = f()
```

b)

```
foo = f()[0]
```

c)

```
def f(return_bar=True):
    if return_bar:
        return foo, bar
    else:
        return foo

foo = f(return_bar=False)
```

Comment: definetly not `C`, `A` is more pythonic

Comment: b) makes sense the most. c) is not scalable and a) just wastes space on a useless object.

Comment: a) is good if you want to skip value in the middle, like for *path, _, files in os.walk(...)*

Comment: @Haris what do you mean by scalable in this context?

Comment: @Max, this cannot be a standard way of doing this because one cannot use this fro cases where a function can return 1, 2 or 3 return values.

Comment: @Haris this was actually exactly the case I had in mind. I thought `a, c = f(return_b=False, return_c=True, return_d=False)` might be nicer than `a, _, c, _ = f()`

Comment: @Max. I don't think so. unnecessary check and parameter handling is needed. Definitely a) or b) is better.

Comment: c) is how `numpy.unique` does it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore python multiple return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431866/ignore-python-multiple-return-value)

Answer (score 6):

You're setting yourself up for trouble if your function returns two variables sometimes and one variable another time.

```
foo, _ = f()
```

Usually using underscore to ignore variables is the standard practice, but in your case, if for whatever reason, this call to `f()` returned only one variable, you will get a runtime error.

Unless you can guarantee that `f()` will return two variables this time, it's better to do this

```
b = f()

if(isinstance(b, tuple)):
    foo = b[0]
```

Comment: "if this call to f() returned only one variable, you will get a runtime error." `foo, *_ = f()` solves this on Python 3. `_` would simply be an empty list.

Comment: where is the `b` coming from? is this a typo?