# Assigning less variables than a function returns

Tags: python

I have a function that returns two variables. However, sometimes I just want to get the output of one variable. What's the most shorthand/concise way to do that? If I just try to set one variable I get a 'Too many values to unpack error'

I tried just leaving the first or second field blank. Look at the code below. Get the same error as before.

Problem:

```py
def function:
 return 1, 2

var1=function()

var1 == 1
```

Tried:

```
var1,=function()
```

I want a notation similar to:

```py
var1,var2=function()

var1,=function()
```

so in this case var 1 should equal 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `_` (underscore), it is used like that for "garbage" values

```py
var1, _ = function()
```

if you don't like that, you can also use indexing

```py
var1 = function()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431866/ignore-python-multiple-return-value), the best practice is the one given by Luke Woodward;

You can use `x = func()[0]` to return the first value, `x = func()[1]` to return the second, and so on. If you want to get multiple values at a time, use something like `x,y = func()[2:4]`.